# Js concurrent processing array causes data duplication

Tags: javascript, arrays

The business is a bit like chat software.
Have an array to hold the contact list.
When receiving a new message, it is necessary to judge that the owner of the message is not in the contact list, and if so, set it to top, otherwise create a new one.
The problem now is that when a large number of messages are received at the same time, there is a judgment at the judgment and insertion interval, resulting in repeated insertion of data.

After the first message arrives, enter the method and iterate over the array... At this point the second message comes and enters the method, causing the data to be repeatedly inserted.
Thanks for reading.

I have no idea.

Main code logic:

```
getMessage() {
   for (...) {
   / / Traverse the array to determine if the contact exists

   // If found, delete at the original index, add at the new index
     contacts.splice(index, 1)
     contacts.splice(newindex, 0, item)
   // If not found, add at the index
     contacts.splice(newindex, 0, item)
   }

}
```

I want to know the right method to deal this question.

Comment: There is no concurrent processing on the same array in javascript. JavaScript behaves as if it would be single threaded.

Comment: You can change your data structure and store the contacts in a map with a list of messages. This will also make your search operation less costly. Also, javascript is single threaded so I am not sure what is causing you so-called concurrent processing issue.

Comment: You seem to make assumptions that go against the nature of the beast. How does the getMessage gets called, how does your code look for getMessage (simplify it down if you don't want to show business related code), with what you have given, there is not a lot of information we can give you...